# How to use node modules like path, net etc in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sqlite

I want to know that how do we use nodejs modules like path, net etc in the react app?
For example, I have an react in which I want to use better-sqlite3 package to fetch a database.
I want to load the database by using path.join() method but path module is not available in react.
How do I do the following?

```
const Database = require(`better-sqlite3`);
const db = new Database(path.join(__dirname, `cliptron.db`));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using a bundler such as Webpack, you can polyfill certain modules. See [this documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback) from Webpack as an example.

These polyfills are only for certain modules, though. The browser doesn't have access to e.g. raw TCP sockets, therefore the `net` module can't be polyfilled in the browser.

As for reading from a database, if it's just a small simple SQLite database or so, you could perform a HTTP GET request to your server for that. Otherwise you'll need to write a server-side API to query the necessary data from your database.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. but, If we write server side API to query the database, will we have to expose it as module or will have to run server as a backend?

Comment: You'll definitely have to create a server/backend with API. You _could_ create a module to help you talk with your API, but might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Oh, ok, seems I'll have to talk to server in order to access the database

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly use packages based on nodejs in react. At least, none that you should take seriously. In order to call your database from the app-side, you would need to expose information regarding your database in order to have the proper credentials to make the connection. In order to communicate with a database you should make a nodejs server-side script utilizing the referenced package which you could then call from your react app to get information from the database.

Comment: Oh, ok, so, what do people do if they feel the need any module like Path?